# Curved div with curved contents

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I've got a circular div that contains a circular image. Around the outside of this image I'd like to put little 'blocks' that run around half of the outside.

It's next to impossible to explain, so I've made a picture:

[image]

It's a lot like that, but the "blocks" would need to be able to have different colours, or be transparent.

I could do it with images (probably quite easily once I'd learned to draw) but I'd rather do it with CSS.

Getting a div full of blocks is easy, but I can't figure out how to "bend" the outer div and have all the contents go with it (in fact, I can't figure out how to bend the outer div at all).

Any ideas?

[edit]I'm getting the feeling after more research and no real movement here that a CSS solution may be impossible, but it might be possible to do something with the Canvas object.

Comment: I don't think this is 'answer worthy' but it may help you. A while back I made this demo, perhaps it can point you in the right direction...
http://jsfiddle.net/32pj5aot/

Comment: here's a start http://jsfiddle.net/2jjdjLw6/ sorry don't have time to finish it now